# Detect output format in conf.py during sphinx-build documentation generation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm adding workarounds to some of the Sphinx's problems straight into `conf.py` file. And I want to write code like this:

```py
if documentation_will_be_generated_as_HTML():
    my_workaround_for_html_docs()
else:
    my_workaround_for_the_rest_of_the_formats()
```

How can predicate `documentation_will_be_generated_as_HTML()` be written for Sphinx?

P.S. I know that it's not good to make workarounds like this, and it's better to make them as extension, but deadlines are strict and tight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sphinx's application API and event handling features to determine which builder that is currently running. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html.

Here is what a handler for the `source-read` event could look like:

```
def workaround(app, docname, source):
    if app.builder.name == "html":
        my_workaround_for_html_docs()
    else:
        my_workaround_for_the_rest_of_the_formats()
 
def setup(app):
    app.connect("source-read", workaround)
```

Some other event might be more appropriate for your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the contents of `sys.argv` inside `conf.py` to determine what [buildername](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-b) is being passed when you execute [`sphinx-build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html). (This is the easiest and direct approach).

What `sys.argv` contains depends on how you are calling `sphinx-build`. If you use `make html` basically you are calling the make file and passing the buildername `html` as the second argument (but the makfile will make one more change to your command-line invocation before calling `sphinx-build`).

Then Inside `conf.py` checking `sys.argv[2]` should contain `html`. (The makefile is usually generated by [`sphinx-quickstart`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-quickstart.html) and may be different between operating systems.)

An excerpt to highlight the relevant lines from a Sphinx `make.bat` batch file on Windows:

```
if "%SPHINXBUILD%" == "" (
    set SPHINXBUILD=sphinx-build
)
set SOURCEDIR=source
set BUILDDIR=build

%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
```

Here's a more complicated example of running `sphinx-build` directly from the command-line with explicit arguments (not using the makefile), it would look like below and in this case `sys.argv[3]` contains the buildername.

```py
>>> sys.argv
['C:/my_venv/Lib/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py', '-E', '-b', 'html', '-d', 'build/doctrees', 'source', 'build/html']

>>> sys.argv[3]
html
```

In conclusion, depending on how you run Sphinx check what `sys.argv` contains in `conf.py` and write your conditions accordingly. In our example, depending on how exactly you invoke `sphinx-build` (or `make html`):

```py
def documentation_will_be_generated_as_HTML():
    if sys.argv[3] == 'html'
        return True


if documentation_will_be_generated_as_HTML():
    my_workaround_for_html_docs()
else:
    my_workaround_for_the_rest_of_the_formats()
```